# Setting Lifestyle of collection items during registration in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

It seems that `Container.Collection.Register` does not have an overload which takes a `Lifestyle`. All discovered implementations will be registered with the default `Lifestyle`. What is the reasoning behind the omission of such an overload?

What is the preferred way of adding a collection where all items should have a `Lifestyle` that is not the default lifestyle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the reasoning behind the omission of such an overload?

First of all, because, (as [Eric Lippert stated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/22/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods/)):

> *no one ever designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped that feature. All six of those things are necessary to make a feature happen. All of them cost*

Second, the `Collection.Register` overloads that accept a list of `Type` instances (e.g. `Collection.Register<TService>(params Type[])`), accept a list of both implementations and abstractions. Supplying a `Lifestyle` for abstractions wouldn't make much sense and is even confusing.

To understand why Simple Injector allows supplying abstractions, take a look at the following registration:

```cs
container.Collection.Register<ILogger>(
    typeof(ILogger),
    typeof(ISpecialLogger),
    typeof(SqlLogger));

container.Register<ILogger, DefaultLogger>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<ISpecialLogger, SpecialLogger>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

In this example, a collection of loggers is registered, where two of the supplied types are abstractions. The idea behind allowing supplying abstractions is that, with it, you can point them to other registrations. This is exactly what the previous example does. When resolving the collection of loggers, it will consist of the `Scoped` `DefaultLogger`, the `Singleton` `SpecialLogger`, and the `Transient` `SqlLogger`.

Now consider a hypothetical new `Collection.Register` overload that accepts a `Lifestyle`:

```cs
container.Collection.Register<ILogger>(new[]
    {
        typeof(ILogger),
        typeof(ISpecialLogger),
        typeof(SqlLogger)
    },
    Lifestyle.Transient);

container.Register<ILogger, DefaultLogger>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<ISpecialLogger, SpecialLogger>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

What does it mean to have the all elements being `Transient`, while two of the elements point to registrations of different lifestyles?

We haven't found a good API that solves these issues (yet), which is why the container is lacking such overload.

> What is the preferred way of adding a collection where all items should have a Lifestyle that is not the default lifestyle?

There are multiple ways to do this.

#### Option 1: Register the element explicitly

Collections, registered in Simple Injector, use a fallback mechanism to determine their lifestyle. This is done by checking whether there exists a concrete registration for the collection's element. For instance:

```cs
container.Collection.Register<ILogger>(typeof(SqlLogger), typeof(FileLogger));

// Ensures that SqlLogger is a Singleton when part of the IEnumerable<ILogger>.
container.Register<SqlLogger>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

When the `IEnumerable<ILogger>` is first resolved by Simple Injector, for each element it will (in the following order):

- Try to get an explicitly registered concrete registration (in the example: `Register<SqlLogger>`
- Try to get that registration using unregistered type resolution
- Try to create the registration itself while making use of the configured `Container.Options.LifestyleSelectionBehavior` (which defaults to `Transient`).

#### Option 2: Use the Register(Type, IEnumerable<Registration>) overload

Instead of supplying a list of types or assemblies to `Collection.Register`, you can also supply a list of `Registration` instances. A `Registration` describes the creation of a certain component for a certain lifestyle and this class is used by Simple Injection internally when you call `Container.Register` or `Container.Collection.Register`. But you can also create `Registration` instances manually and supply them to a `Collection.Register` overload as follows:

```cs
// Load the list of types without registering them
Type[] types = container.GetTypesToRegister<ILogger>(assemblies);

// Register them using the overload that takes in a list of Registrations
container.Collection.Register<ILogger>(
    from type in types
    select Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration(type, container));
```

This forces all registered types of the collection to have the `Transient` lifestyle. You can also give each type its own specific lifestyle if you want.

#### Option 3: Override LifestyleSelectionBehavior

When no registration can be found, `Collection.Register` makes the registration itself, last minute, using the configured `LifestyleSelectionBehavior`. The default selection behavior always returns `Lifestyle.Transient`, but this behavior can be changed. For instance:

```cs
class CustomLifestyleSelectionBehavior : ILifestyleSelectionBehavior
{
    public Lifestyle SelectLifestyle(Type implementationType) =>
        implementationType == typeof(SqlLogger)
            ? Lifestyle.Singleton
            : Lifestyle.Transient;
}
```

This implementation if, obviously, a bit naive, but shows the concept. You can override the default behavior as follows:

```cs
container.Options.LifestyleSelectionBehavior =
    new CustomLifestyleSelectionBehavior();
```

#### Option 4: Append

Next to `Collection.Register`, which allows the registration of all elements in one go, you can make use of the `Collection.Append` methods. They allow one-by-one registration of collection elements:

```cs
container.Collection.Append<ILogger, SqlLogger>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.Collection.Append<ILogger, FileLogger>(Lifestyle.Transient);
```

There are also non-generic overloads available, which simplify auto-registering these types, for instance when returned using `Container.GetTypesToRegister`.

These are your basic options in Simple Injector v4.6. We might decide to add a convenient `Collection.Register<T>(IEnumerable<Type>, Lifestyle)` overload in the future, as the ommision of this overload does cause some confusion from time to time.

Comment: Cool, the quote of Eric Lippert actually crossed my mind when I wrote down the first question ;-)

The documentation on `Collection.Append` threw me off a bit (and I could have tested before asking the question), as I thought it could only be used on top of `Collection.Register`.

Comment: If you have anyy suggestions for improving the append documentation, please let me know.

Comment: Well, the documentation for the `Append` overloads all explicitly state that the new registration will be appended to *existing* registrations made `using one of the Collection.Register overloads`. As it turns out, `Append` can also be used as a starting point. So perhaps add something in the lines of:
`If no such call was made, Append will create the collection.`

Comment: Good point. Thanks for your suggestion. Will queue this improvement for the next release. I think that the documentation was correct up to some point in time, but Simple Injector evolved, but the documentation wasn't updated.

Comment: @AroglDarthu: There was an option missing from my answer. I updated my answer with a new "option 2".

Comment: The new second option suits our needs perfectly. Just curious though: is there a drawback (performance wise or other) to option 4 when compared to option 2? I would imagine both options create a Registration for each type and register it with the container.

Comment: Option 2 basically does an `Append` for each supplied `Registration`. From a resolve perspective they are equivalent; from a registration perspective, option 2 might be a bit more performant, but this would typically not be something to worry about.

Comment: note: I dig a bit deeper in the code base to find out why this feature is missing. I updated my answer accordingly.